# About the possibility of extending the solution of a PDE on a subset of $R^n$ to the entire $R^n$.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, manifolds

I do not have any background in either the theory of PDEs or differential geometry, but I've come across this question to which I think the techniques of the two fields might help (certainly the theory of second order PDEs) but I don't really know where to start to look for the answer so if someone can kindly point me to the right reference, I would really appreciate it.

The question is the following. Let $U$ be a connected open, bounded set in $R^d$, let $\phi \in C_b^\infty(U)$ (smooth with bounded derivatives of all orders), $a \in C^\infty(U,R^d \otimes R^d)$ is symmetric and positive definite, let 
\begin{equation} Lf \equiv \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i,j = 1}^d a_{i,j} \frac{ \partial^2 f}{\partial x_i \partial x_j} \end{equation}

Suppose $f \in C^{1,2}((0,T) \times U) \cap C([0,T] \times U)$ is such that

\begin{equation} \begin{cases} f(T, \cdot) = \phi(\cdot) \\ \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial t} + L \right) f(t,x) = 0 \text{ for } (t,x) \in (0,T) \times U  \end{cases} \end{equation}

Is it true (if not in general then under what conditions) that $Lf$ has *bounded* spatial derivatives of order 2?